# Listen to Service Worker Push events from GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, gatsby

I have `gatsby-offline-plugin` installed and I'm trying to use the service worker to recieve push events. I can't seem to listen to the events for them.

I tried listening to them like this:

```
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateFound = ({ serviceWorker }) => {    
  serviceWorker.addEventListener('push', event => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.', event);
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);
  });
}
```

Also like this:

```
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateFound = ({ serviceWorker }) => {
  self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.', event);
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);
  });
}
```

Nothing seems to be logged out. Also `Self` seems to be just the window object in the second instance

I can subscribe successfully (i get the endpoint and keys) but trying to publish to that endpoint has no effect. I also tried to use the "push" commands in the chrome dev tools but no luck.

Any idea if this is supported? or how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

for everyone running in to this problem. You can solve this problem by either creating a completely custom service worker or you can add an extension script to the existing service worker.

### The extension script

In your root static folder add your extension for example: sw-extension.js and add your event listeners here.

```
// sw-extension.js
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
})
```

and then add these options to the offline plugin in your gatsby-config file.

```
//gatsby-config.js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  options: {
      importScripts: [`./sw-extension.js`],
  },
},
```

### custom service worker

add the following code to your gatsby-browser file and add a file named sw.js to your static folder.

```
// gatsby-browser.js
export const registerServiceWorker = () => true
```